# Trouble appending values across the rows using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I've written a script in python to read some value from an excel file and then again write the populated item right next to the concerning rows. However, when It comes to appending values next to the rows, I get stuck.

Here is my try:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('item.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
for row in ws["A4":"D4"]:
    data = [cell.value for cell in row]
    ws.append(data)
    wb.save("New_File.xlsx")
```

The populated values are `12 13 14 15` derived from `A4` to `D4`. Now i wish to append the same values in the next rows, as in `12 13 14 15` will be again in `E4` to `H4`. 
And the final output should look like `12 13 14 15 12 13 14 15` in `A4` to `H4`.

My above script is appending the values to the last row. How can i rectify my script to serve the purpose? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('item.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
mRow = ws.max_row
for row in ws["A4":"D4"]:
    data = [cell.value for cell in row]
x = 5

for item in data:
    ws.cell(row = ws._current_row, column = x).value = item
    x+=1

wb.save("New_File.xlsx")
```